How to control change of exposure/colour between images when taking a timelapse?
I have a Sony a5100 and a timelapse app, and generally it works great, but I noticed that some pictures vary in colour and/or exposure. Now, I used Manual settings, turned every automation off, but it still occurs.
How can I fix or prevent this?

Are you thinking this is something that your camera is doing, or is the scene actually changing over time, e.g., a cloud blocking the sun for some photos?

Hey there, no, its something the camera is doing.. Its darker, brighter, darker, darker, brighter.. But I may have found the solution.. It seems that when doing timelapses the shatter speed needs to be double of the frames per second, so I hav 50, and so the shatter speed needs to be 1/100, and right now it seems that solved the issue..

@SimonDaum, small clarification. The rule is shutter speed is good to be 50% of the time between frames. You can check here: https://wistia.com/learn/production/what-is-shutter-speed

A time-lapse with images every 1/50s is called a "movie", no?

Please include some examples and their meta data to help your answer get solved
